# Quadrilateral Proof Using Triangles

Tags: geometry

In square $ABCD$, $E$ is the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$, and $F$ is the midpoint of $\overline{CD}$. Let $G$ be the intersection of $\overline{AE}$ and $\overline{BF}$. Prove that $DG = AB$.
[image: Diagram]

Stared at this problem for fifteen minutes and I still have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By congruent triangles, $\angle 1 = \angle 2 = \angle 3$.

[image]

Also, $\angle 3 = \angle 4$.

$\angle 4 = \angle 2$ means ADFG is cyclic. This further means $\angle 1 = \angle 5$.

Result follows from  $\angle 4 = \angle 5$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove that $\angle AGC=\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{3\pi}{4}=135^\circ$.  This is equivalent to showing that $\angle CFG=\frac{\pi}{4}=45^\circ$.  However, as $CEGF$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, we have $$\angle CGF=\angle CEF=\frac{\pi}{4}\,.$$

---

Using analytic geometry in this problem is quite straightforward too.  Setting $A=(0,1)$, $B=(1,1)$, $C=(1,0)$, and $D=(0,0)$ yields $G=\left(\frac{4}{5},\frac{3}{5}\right)$, whence $GD=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: Triangle $AEB$ is congruent to triangle $BFC$ so $\angle AEB = \angle BFC = \angle GFC$. Also $\angle AEB = \angle DAE = \angle GAD$ because $BC$ is parallel to $AD$. Consequently, since $\angle GFC = \angle BFC = \angle DAE = \angle GAD$, the four points $A, D, F, G$ lie on a common circle so $\angle AGF = \pi - \angle ADF = \pi - \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$, i.e. $AE$ is perpendicular to $BF$.

Alternatively, we can look at the center $O$ of the square $ABCD$, i.e. $O$ is the intersection point of the two diagonals. Then if we perform a counterclockwise $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rotation around $O$, triangle $BFC$ is rotated to triangle $AEB$ therefore, in particular, $BF$ is rotated to $AE$ meaning that $BF$ is perpendicular to $AE$.

Extend $BF$ to a line until it intersects the line $AD$ in a point $B_1$. Then triangles $FCB$ and $FDB_1$ are congruent so $BC = DB_1$, meaning that $AD = DB_1$. Thus $D$ is the midpoint of $AB_1$ and since $AB_1G$ is a right angled triangle with $\angle AGB_1 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and the segment $DG$ is a median, $DG = \frac{AB_1}{2} = AD = AB$.